# How to find a button by name

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

So, I have 2 buttons in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="but1"  />
<Button Click="button_Click"  Tag="but1" />
```

and I want to fiind first button when second button is pressed and add it to a ListBox like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //this is only how I imagine this to be
            string buttonName = (sender as Button).Tag.ToString();
            Button findedButton = Find(buttonName);
            ListBox1.Items.Add(findedButton);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this. Where Layout Root is your overall layout inside the layout you want to find an item by the name it will most likely return an object and you have to check if it a button then you found what you were looking for.

```
object item = LayoutRoot.FindName(buttonName);
if(item is Button)
{
  Button btn=(Button)item;
}
```

Comment: this throw me the error that Element is already the child of another element. :(